# Object property references in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am confused with the concept of JavaScript object referencing. Let's say we have an object with a method property called `greet` and we store the method in variable called `sayIt`. When we call that variable with the stored method property it returns `undefined` because it is referencing the global object instead of the person object with property `firstName`.

Why does it return `undefined` when it is referencing the object? Here is an example:

```
var person = {
  firstName : 'Boaz',
  lastName : 'Sender',
  greet : function() {
    console.log( 'Hi, ' + this.firstName );
  }
};

var sayIt = person.greet; // store the method in a variable

sayIt(); // logs 'Hi, undefined' -- uh-oh
```

Comment: Methods are not "attached" to the objects. Methods literally have no idea what object it is called with until you call it. In case of `sayIt();` as you can see you don't have any object in the call.

Comment: @AndrewLi: no, that question has nothing to do with it

Comment: @Bergi It seems, my mistake.

Comment: @zerkms It also helps calling them "functions" not methods. Only when you call the function on the object, it's a *method invocation* :-)

Comment: JavaScript is object based and uses a *this context*. Not the definition, but the invocation sets the *this context*. When you call the method as a global variable, the this context will be the window object. Thus this.firstName references window.firstName, which is undefined.

Comment: try passing the context using `call` as in `var sayIt = person.greet.call(person);` or `person.greet();`. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Bergi and for that reason I don't like that the standard uses the "method" term at all - they are all functions.